# XMPP query archive - full text search

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I am new to ejabberd and trying to find out, how do i do full text search in history of messages for particular user? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Message Archive Management XMPP specification does not support the full text query search and ejabberd does not implement something specific in that regard.

You have to implement your custom protocol and search feature. You can likely rely on database features for full-text search to make that easier (either MySQL or Pgsql)

Comment: by implementing custom protocol, you mean writing new module to ejabberd which require knowledge of erlang right ? Or is there any other way? Maybe something like forwarding all messages to another storage/system/backend system via API and do store & search there ?

Comment: I mean you can extend XMPP with specific stanza for Full Text Search queries. You can implement the logic either inside ejabberd in Erlang or Elixir, or write an external XMPP component in any programming languages that will handle those requests query the database and send proper reply.

Comment: @MickaëlRémond Can you please tell me the IQ request for fetching archives message that contains body ? OR using any element I mean tag like <store> tag.

Comment: @JakubKuchar Please let me know if you find any solution for this.